# Protecting sensitive data when giving the laptop to a technician

Tags: boot, security, encryption

Suppose that my laptop does not boot and I have to give it to a technician for repair. This gives the technician access to my hard-drive and all the material in it.

I can take out or encrypt the hard-drive, but then the technician will not be able to boot in order to validate the problem or verify that the problem was solved.

Is there a way to let the technician freely boot into my machine (using a guest account), and at the same time, prevent the technician from viewing personal data on my computer?

Comment: Encrypting just your home folder is a common solution.

Comment: get a cheap hard drive, install Ubuntu on it, swap with existing hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Important to note:

- If you give your system to a bad guy you should consider it as compromised and it could not be trusted any more.

Short answer to:

> Is there a way to let the technician freely boot into my machine (using a guest account), and at the same time, prevent the technician from viewing personal data on my computer?

- Encrypt your HOME directory (Can't protect you against all possibilities)

---

What you have to do?

1. Don't give it to anyone you don't trust
2. If you have to:

   - Remove the important parts (like hard disk).
   - Keep track of device's frameware information if it's possible (ex: BIOS details [which can be faked anyway] )

If you can't remove the hard disk, then encryption is the best you have.   However remember that even encryption can be attacked using different methods.

- As a simple example they can compromise the boot partition on your full encrypted hard disk to find your passphrase.
- Change the programs on your root to find the passphrase of encrypted home directory.
- Or real attacks like investigating your memory, cloning your hard disk.

In your situation the best way that I can consider is encrypting your `HOME` directory. So they can boot into your system and fix the issue but  can't access your data.

After you get your laptop back consider re-installing your operating system, and checking what you keep track of to make sure nothing has been changed.

And remember as my explanations suggests, the device could be physically compromised too.

- So... Don't give it to a bad guy.

Comment: how can  a device be physically compromised???

Comment: @BЈовић One could install a hardware keylogger into the device to log any decryption passhprase or other credentials that are being entered. The hard drive could even be cloned to attempt a offline bruteforcing the passphrase

Comment: @BЈовић stick in a keylogger inside the laptop

Comment: they could have installed a BIOS Rootkit too, so reinstall the BIOS. Then take it all apart to make sure there is no hardware keylogger... maybe don't give it to the bad guy.